# How to make a JSON object readable in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, webapp2

I have passed a variable from Javascript using this AJAX call:

```
var creationSuccess = function (data) {
  console.log('Card created successfully.');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  var url = "/ajaxtest";
  $.post(url, {card_id: data.id});
};
```

Which gets passed to this Python method:

```
class AjaxTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(card_id):
        data = card_id
        logging.info(data)
```

However when I print `data` I get this in the console:

`<main.AjaxTest object at 0x107607510>`

How do I turn this object into a readable form that I can work with?

Comment: Every normal python method that is part of a class uses the first argument to pass a reference to the class in, similar to javascript's `this`. Generally, name this variable `self`, so `card_id` is actually just a reference to `self`, not the data that's coming through the request. When you're logging `data`, you're actually logging the class.

Comment: The JSON is stored in the data variable,  Python is not aware that this is a JSON object.You will have to use  request.get_json()

Comment: Oh I see, OK so I have added `self` to the method parameters but now I get an error saying `post() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: `post()` only takes one argument.  It doesn't technically matter whether it's named `card_id`, `self`, or something else, but the standard convention is to name it `self`.  So remove `card_id` from the argument list, leaving only `self`.  To get the data that was posted, look at `self.request.POST`.